# How to stop a running script after parsing output from the script?

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have a perl script that prints out a menu and waits for user input. I want to be able to parse that menu for some numbers using awk, but the user input part is complicating things.

What I have so far:

```
script.pl | awk '$1 ~ /\d*\./ { print $1 }'
```

The above one liner (that may not be the most optimal) prints out

```
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
7.
8.
9.
10.
```

...but there is a blinking cursor at the end that's waiting for input. I'd like to be able to exit without doing a keyboard interrupt.

Comment: provide input? `echo foo|script|awk`?

Comment: The "waiting for input" problem is due to `script.pl` _not_ `awk` and you haven't told us anything about `script.pl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Marc B's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) comment worked:

```
echo foo|script|awk
```

I was overthinking the problem and neglected to try providing input. Luckily the script exits immediately after giving it an empty string.

Comment: In that case, `: | script.pl | awk '$1 ~ /\d*\./ { print $1 }'` should work as well.